# Uploaded my app without "com." in its bundle identifier

Tags: ios, app-store, bundle, appstore-approval, identifier

So instead of my new app's bundle ID being "com.myName.myAppName", it is "myName.myAppName". I have another app in the app store with the "com." ID. 
Will they reject this new one? Should I reject it myself and reupload it?

Thanks

Comment: Are these two different apps?

Comment: yes, the first is approved and has the full bundle ID: "com.myName.myAppName". the second one i just uploaded and it has the short bundle ID: "myName.myAppName"

Comment: Even if they do not reject, I would re-submitt using a proper identifier. You'll be happier later.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns the policies and procedures of app distribution services, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?‍](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?(https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score 1):

While we create new Application Identifier, Its more preferred to use the pattern like com.companyname.appname. However there is no hard or mandatory rules that you must follow such patterns.

So even if you are not using such pattern there is no chances or case to lead your application rejected.

Specifically in iOS bundle name is not getting displayed anywhere on the store to the users. Only developers can view it & its specifically created to uniquely identify your applications on your store.

Hope this helps to everyone.